# Confused about the definition of $\mathcal O_{\operatorname{Spec}A}(U)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, definition, schemes

Consider $\operatorname{Spec} A$ for some ring $A$.

When defining the structure sheaf, Hartshorne defines

> For an open subset $U \subset \operatorname{Spec}(A)$, we define $\mathcal O(U)$ to be the set of all functions $s: U \to \coprod_{\mathfrak p \in U} A_{\mathfrak p}$, such that:
> i.) $s(\mathfrak p) \in A_{\mathfrak p}$
> ii.) for each $\mathfrak{p} \in U$, there is a neighborhood $V$ of $\mathfrak p$, contained in $U$, and elements $a, f \in A$ such that for each $\mathfrak q \in V$, we have $f \notin \mathfrak q$ and $s(\mathfrak q) = a/f \in A_{\mathfrak q}$.

In Eisenbud/Harris, after defining general schemes they write:

> if $f \in \mathcal O_X(U)$ and $x \in U$, the image of $f$ under the composite $\mathcal O_X(U) \to \mathcal O_{X,x} \to \mathcal O_{X,x}/\mathfrak m_x$ is the value of $f$ at $x$.

If we take $X=\operatorname{Spec}A$, then these two definitions seem to be saying different things.

Hartshorne is saying $s \in \mathcal O(U)$ takes $\mathfrak p \in U$ to an element in $A_\mathfrak p$, whereas Eisenbud/Harris is saying $s \in \mathcal O(U)$ takes $\mathfrak p$ to an element of $A_\mathfrak p/ \mathfrak m_\mathfrak p$

What is going on here?

Comment: Actually, the notation $s(\mathfrak{p})$ of Hartshorne is somewhat misleading. It’s not evaluation at $\mathfrak{p}$ of the section $s$. Given condition (ii) of Hartshorne, $s(\mathfrak{p})$ is rather the *stalk* of the section $s$ at $\mathfrak{p}$ – so you need to quotient by the maximal ideal to get the evaluation. If that helps you better understand the construction, note that the Hartshorne $\mathcal{O}$ is the sheafification of the “partially defined presheaf” $D(f) \longmapsto A_f$.

Comment: In both settings you can view $s$ as taking $\mathfrak{p}$ to an element in $A_\mathfrak{p}$.

Eisenbud Harris says that, additionally, there is a map (of rings) $\mathcal{O}_{Spec(A)}(U)\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{Spec(A),\mathfrak{p}}=A_\mathfrak{p}$ given by $s\mapsto a/f \in A_\mathfrak{p}$ and a map from $A_\mathfrak{p}$ to $A_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{m}_\mathfrak{p}$ given by taking the quotient.

As Mindlack says, the first map is "taking the stalk" and the composition with the second one is "evaluating".

Comment: Consider $X = \operatorname{Spec} k[x,y]$. Take $s=\dfrac{x^2+y^2}{x(y^2-x^5)} \in \mathcal O_X (D(x(y^2-x^5))) = k[x,y]_{x(y^2-x^5)}$. What is $s((x-2,y-4))$?

Comment: Is $s((x-2, y-4)) = \dfrac{x^2+y^2}{x(y^2-x^5)} \in k[x,y]_{(x-2, y-4)}$ or is $s((x-2, y-4)) = \dfrac{2^2+4^2}{2(4^2-2^5)}$?